# What is the scope of a local variable appended to a global array?

Tags: swift

In the following example, what is the scope of `localVariable`?

Is the object in `anArray[0] === localVariable`? Will `localVariable` persist until `Example` goes out of scope (from wherever it is constructed)?

```
class Example {
    var anArray: [DataClass] = []

    init() {
        let localVariable = DataClass()
        anArray.append(localVariable)
    }
}

class DataClass { }
```

Comment: localVariable will no longer exist after the initializer finishes. Its value however is still kept alive inside the anArray. The instance of DataClass will only be deallocated once nobody is referencing it anymore - meaning that as soon as the Example instance gets deallocated the DataClass gets deallocated as well (if nobody accesses the anArray from the outside and retrieves its values)

Comment: Can you explain what problem you encounter? Is there a problem or are you just curious?

Comment: @luk2302 I think you're right - but your wording about 'value' concerns me. Because it is a class, I believe the actual reference to the object will be copied.

Comment: @Jelle Just curious. :D

Comment: okay, value being "the class instance it references to"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding it to the array will increment the retain count, so yes, it will exist until the array is destroyed (when the example instance is removed) unless it is added to some other variable/array/set/reference somewhere else as well.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was after!

Comment: Just a small warning: retain cycles or self referencing might keep objects alive longer (or forever) than expected or intended. E.g. this can happen when using closures (blocks) or timers or non-weak delegates.